# Throw error if JTextField is empty

Tags: java, swing, exception

I am trying to write a try catch block that will throw an exception if the user does not enter a name and just presses `enter` or `okay` I seem to be having issues because it doesn't throw anything it just accepts the blank and continues. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

here is the function:

```
public String setOwnerName() {
        boolean isName = false;

        while(!isName) {
            try {
                this.ownerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the account owner's name.", "Owner's Name", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                if(this.ownerName != "") {
                    isName = true;  
                }
            } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error you did not enter a name, please try again.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        return this.ownerName;
    }
```

Comment: Entering nothing and pressing enter doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun okay so how would i throw an error if the field is left empty?

Comment: Don't throw an error, use simple `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty name does not trow `exception`. You need to manually check it. Try,

```
public String setOwnerName() {
  boolean isName = false;

while(!isName) {               
 ownerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the account owner's name.",
               "Owner's Name", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

  if(ownerName.trim().isEmpty()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        "Error you did not enter a name, please try again.", 
       "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
  else{
      isName = true;
      }               
   }// end of while

    return ownerName;
}
```

Comment: It is still bypassed by just typing a space is there a way to check that too? i tried `&& ownerName != " "` but that did not work

Comment: @zachstarnes use like this if(ownerName.trim().isEmpty())

Comment: @zachstarnes, Yes you need trim() to skip spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
 try{           
      if(ownerName.trim().isEmpty()) 
      {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input is wrong");
      }
 } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {

 }
```